# `rails generate scaffold_controller` doesn't respond to args for views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor

in the `scaffold_controller` help (`rails generate scaffold_controller -h`)

> > Pass the model name,
> >         either CamelCased or under_scored, **and a list of views as arguments**.

when I add enter something like

```
rails generate scaffold_controller Page home
```

I get all of the REST actions and views, but no home view.

I checked the rails repo history back to the birth of the scaffold_controller generator [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/35c4df4aa5812abcd5928c31c1e673e32434b751#diff-5) and I see nothing that seems to accept arguments, but the same documentation.

**Is this just an overlooked error or am I entering in my arguments incorrectly (or something else ;)?**

#### Update

It seems like I was looking for `rails generate controller Page home` all along.  There still seems to be a bug in the documentation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
rails generate controller Page home
```

will produce the expected result for you, although it is missing generation of regular show/index/update/destroy methods in the controller.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  And scaffold_controller is if you want the REST actions... I see.  I will still file a bug about the docs though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just must to pass model fields like this :

```
rails generate scaffold_controller Page title:string description:text
```

If you want to generate some views, you must to do this :

```
rails generate controller Page home
```